# Why does python return a "None-value" when asked to return math.pi?

Tags: python-3.x, math

I'm doing a homework assignment, and the task is to round `math.pi` with a number given in the function `pi(d=0)`. So if you enter pi(2) the function will return 3.14. If you enter more than 15 in the function, it will print 'Too many decimals,' and also return math.pi. My problem is that my function now returns `math.pi` and a "None-value"

I've tried different approaches, including different if-statements and removing the print-statement completely. This fixes the problem, but I won't be answering my assignment

```
import math
def pi(d=0):

    if d<=15:
         return round((math.pi), d)
    if d>15:
         return math.pi, print('Too many decimals!')
```

I expect the output of if `d>15` to be `Too many decimals!, 3.141592653589793`

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
print('Too many decimals!')
```

**does** print `'Too many decimals!'`, but its value is `None`. That means

```
return x, print('foo')
```

will return the tuple `(x, None)` with the side effect of outputting `'foo'` to the console. You could simply return the string itself instead:

```
return math.pi, 'Too many decimals!'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return math.pi, print('Too many decimals!')
```

The return statement always returns a single value; in this case, because you use the comma between two values, it returns a *tuple* of two elements.

Let's rewrite the line, while it still does exactly the same thing:

```
result = (math.pi, print('Too many decimals!'))
return result
```

So here we see that the first element of the tuple is math.pi, and the second is whatever value print('Too many decimals!') returns: `None`.

Instead this does what you meant:

```
print('Too many decimals!')
return math.pi
```